# How to access iLO on hp DL 380 from different network?

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

I have an hp DL380 G7 in a 10.0.0.0 network. When I VPN into the network my PC gets assigned an ip in the 10.0.8.0 network. I cannot ping my iLO interface from this network. However I can ping it from a different machine in the 10.0.0.0 network.

Where can I change the configuration so that I can access iLO outside of the 10.0.0.0 network? I've checked my firewall and it allows all traffic from 10.0.8.0 to 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Is it only the ping that is not working? Or also http/https? As far as i know, many firewalls block ICMP over the gateway, even if firewall rules allow connections between the networks.

Comment: @Tobias I cannot access the website either. I can ping other machines on the 0 network from the 8 network fine. It's just the iLO I can't access. When the server power is on, I can access the server itself fine from the 8 network, but not iLO.

Comment: At the moment i do not have HP servers, but i worked with them before. And i do not remember any setting that would block traffic from external subnets... If traffic to other systems in the same subnets is working fine, i would at first check the gateway in the network settings of ILO.

Comment: @Tobias that was it! Incorrect default gateway in the iLO network config. Do you want to submit as an answer and I'll accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment i do not have HP servers, but i worked with them before. And i do not remember any setting that would block traffic from external subnets... If traffic to other systems in the same subnets is working fine, i would at first check the gateway in the network settings of ILO.